# Properties of a convex set

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be convex and closed, $y \in \partial C$.

Show that there is an affine $f(x)=\langle x-y,e \rangle$ where $|e|=1$, such that $f(y)=0$ and $\forall x \in C: f(x) \leq 0$

Notation:
Let me explain my notation, in case there is some confusion:
$\langle -,- \rangle$ is the euclidean scalar product and $|\cdotp |$ is the derived norm.

Also I want to add some things I already know that could be interesting here: 
(1) $\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash C: ! \exists c \in C \text{such that} |v-c|=\min_{x \in C}|v-x|$

(2) For $v$ and $c$ like in (1): $\forall x \in C: \langle x-c,\frac{v-c}{|v-c|} \rangle \leq 0$

Geometrically if I am not completely wrong you could imagine $e$ as standing orthogonally on $y$ so the scalar product would be always negative. 
(Sorry for the awful formatting, I will try to improve my latex-skills! If something is not clear, don't hesitate to ask.)

Comment: This result is called *supporting hyperplane theorem*. You can find a proof on page 4 of [these slides](https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/angelia/www/L7_separationthms.pdf). Note also that your functional $f$ is *not* linear (since $f(0) = \langle -y, e \rangle \neq 0$ in general) but rather affine. Otherwise, your intuition is quite good, by the way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You are right I corrected it to say affine. But maybe is there a straight forward way to show it from what I already have?

Comment: That's the [supporting hyperplane theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supporting_hyperplane), right?

Comment: you are looking for the support plane at the point $y$ for the convex set $c$ and $e$ would be the unit vector orthogonal to that support plane. i am assuming that you know the proof for the existence of a support plane at boundary points of any convex set.

Comment: @abel: no that's what user3123 is looking for.

Comment: To find the vector $e$, you can proceed as follows. Approximate the boundary point $y$ from *outside* $C$ with a sequence $x_k$ in $C \smallsetminus X$. Let $c_k$ be the projection of $x_k$ to $C$. The sequence $z_k = \frac{x_k - c_k}{\|x_k - c_k\|}$ is a sequence in the compact unit sphere $S^{n-1}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. You can therefore extract a convergent subsequence $z_{k_n} \to e \in S^{n-1}$ and you can check that $\langle e,c \rangle \leq \langle e, y \rangle$ for all $c \in C$.

Comment: Thank you for this guide, the two parts I don't know is: a) what is the projection of $x_k$ to $C$? (how it is defined) b) why is $z_k$ in the unit sphere, is it because it is bounded? Also you could write it as a full answer if you want because it will pretty much do the deal for me :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll write it out in a moment. Here's a brief answer first. a) For $v \in \mathbb{R}^n \smallsetminus C$ you have a unique $c \in C$ closest to it by your property (1), write $v_k = x_k$ and $c_k$ is the corresponding point. As for b), just note that $\|z_k\| = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, you can find a proof on page 4 in [these slides](https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/angelia/www/L7_separationthms.pdf) (found by Googling for `supporting hyperplane theorem, proof`). The slides refer to chapter 2.5 of Boyd and Vanderberghe's book *[Convex optimization](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/)* (free download on Boyd's webpage), see pages 46ff of the book.

Using what you know, you can prove it as follows.

1. Choose a sequence $v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n \smallsetminus C$ such that $v_k \to y$. Such a sequence exists by the property that $y \in \partial C$ and $C$ is a proper closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
2. Let $c_k \in C$ be the unique point closest to $v_k$ by (1), so $c_k$ has the property $|v_k - c_k| = \inf_{c \in C} |v_k - c|$.
3. Moreover, by (2) we know that for all $x \in C$ we have $\displaystyle \left\langle x - c_k, \frac{v_k - c_k}{|v_k - c_k|}\right\rangle \leq 0$ for all $x \in C$.
4. Put $z_k = \frac{v_k - c_k}{|v_k - c_k|}$. Note that $|z_k| = 1$ so that $z_k \in S^{n-1} = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\,:\,|y| =1 \}$. The equation in step 3. now reads $\langle x - c_k, z_k \rangle \leq 0$ for all $x \in C$.
5. Since $S^{n-1}$ is compact, we can extract a convergent subsequence $z_{k_j} \to e \in S^{n-1}$. Note that $|e| = 1$ by definition.
6. For all $x \in C$ and all $j$ we have $\langle x - c_{k_j}, z_{k_j} \rangle \leq 0$. Now let $j \to \infty$ to obtain $\langle x - y, e \rangle \leq 0$ for all $x \in C$ since $c_{k_j} \to y$ and $z_{k_j} \to e$ and the limit of non-positive numbers is non-positive.

To finish all up, let $f(x) = \langle x - y, e \rangle$ and note that $f$ has all the desired properties, as we established in step 6.

Comment: Thank you, now I fully understood it.